# Google Play Services Error in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services

I implement the Google Play Services with `GameHelper` and `GameHelperUltis.` So my problem is if I test my app in Android Studio on my device it works perfect and I can use the Service with leaderboards and achievements. So now if I upload the APK on google play and I download my game and start it come to this error:

```
The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.
```

But why?

Comment: Please make sure you fully uninstall the application before installing it again. It's possible that if you have it installed, it's seeing it as an upgrade, since they have the same package names. Installing from android studio and then from play store will usually have different signing keys too, which would cause errors.

Comment: i do it but the error comes back